# Assert two IList<IWebElement> selenium c#

Tags: selenium, c#

I have taken two outputs  which are `IList<IWebElement>`  type from the UI and the Database.
So now i need to compair the two `IList<IWebElement>` .
Im using nunit.
How to perform this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an `IEqualityComparer` that implements the `Equals` and the `GetHashCode` methods according to your logic of comparison.

```
class WebElementEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IWebElement>
{
    public bool Equals(IWebElement w1, IWebElement w2)
    {
        return true; //put your comparison logic here
    }
    public int GetHashCode(IWebElement wx)
    {
        int hCode = 1111; //put your logic of creating a hash code from your IWebElement here
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the above newly created comparer as below:

```
IList<IWebElement> db = ...// your IList comming from DB
IList<IWebElement> ui = ...// your IList comming from UI
// assert this value is true
Assert.IsTrue(db.SequenceEqual(ui, new WebElementEqualityComparer()));
// or false as expected
Assert.IsFalse(db.SequenceEqual(ui, new WebElementEqualityComparer()));
```

I hope it helps.

- Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19553574/3652270
- NUnit condition assertions: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.True